# exiftool width and height of resized images not match the new sizes

Tags: imagemagick, exiftool

```
$ convert original.jpg -resize 50% test.jpg

$ exiftool test.jpg 
...
Exif Image Width                : 1200
Exif Image Height               : 1600
Image Width                     : 600
Image Height                    : 800
Image Size                      : 600x800
```

The size of original.jpg is 1200 x 1600.

After resizing the image by half, why are the Exif Image Width and Exif Image Height not the same as Image Width and Image Height?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The Convert command doesn't modify the metadata.  The Exif tags still hold the info from the previous image.  You could fix that using this ExifTool command:

```
exiftool "-ExifImageHeight<ImageHeight" "-ExifImageWidth<ImageWidth" test.jpg
```

If you're not using windows, change double quotes to single quotes.

..

Comment: These quotes work on Unix et al, as well.

Comment: In this case, yes. But it's a good idea to be in the habit of using single quotes with exiftool on Mac/Linux/Powershell as many exiftool commands include a dollar sign, which would be interpreted as a  shell variable with double quotes.  This was a copy/paste which I add to most of my exiftool answers.